# MySQL Combine SELECT results in rows

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have 2 identical tables like these:

```
table1              table2
+--------+------+   +--------+------+
| fruit  | year |   | fruit  | year |
+--------+------+   +--------+------+
| apple  | 2015 |   | apple  | 2014 |
| banana | 2014 |   | apple  | 2013 |
| banana | 2013 |   | banana | 2011 |
+--------+------+   +--------+------+
```

I'd like to get the last year for the fruits in each table like so:

```
+--------+---------+---------+
| fruit  | t1.last | t2.last |
+--------+---------+---------+
| apple  |   2015  |   2014  |
| banana |   2014  |   2011  |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

For a single table it's possible with a simple SELECT statement:

```
SELECT fruit, max( year ) AS last FROM table1 GROUP BY fruit
result:
+--------+------+
| fruit  | last |
+--------+------+
| apple  | 2015 |
| banana | 2014 |
+--------+------+
```

What I don't know is how to 'append' the last year for each fruit from the second table as an adjacent row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `JOIN` the two tables.

```
SELECT fruit,
    max(t1.year) AS `t1.last`,
    max(t2.year) AS `t2.last`
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 USING(fruit)
GROUP BY fruit
```

DEMO: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3b71/1

Comment: Is it possible to also get the count() of the fruits in each table?

Comment: @gipadm: You can just simply add `count(fruit)`, but this will return 2 (the number of *unique* fruits) since you are doing `GROUP BY fruit`.

Comment: That's my problem, I need it to return 1 and 2 for the first table. So it's not possible?

Comment: @gipadm: What values are you looking for exactly?  It may not be possible all in one query.

Comment: It should return t1.count [1 (apple)] [2 (banana)] t2.count [2 (apple)] [1 (banana)] . I forgot to include it in the original question.

Comment: @gipadm: Because of the `JOIN` and the `GROUP BY`, you cannot properly count the number of fruits from each table.  You can possibly use subqueries to do this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3b71/12

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.fruit, max(t1.year ) AS t1last, max(t2.year ) AS t2last 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.fruit = t2.fruit GROUP BY t1.fruit
```

Try that

Comment: Is it possible to also get the count() of the fruits in each table?